# MySQL Group by consecutive values and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 10 |
| 11 |

So a bunch of consecutive values, an unknown number of absent fields and then other consecutive values.
What I am trying to achieve is to get

| id | stint |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 |

By incrementing every time the number of the stint, which I can later use for summing over other columns.
Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your MySQL version support window function.

You can try to use `LAG` window function in subquery to get previous `id` column, then use `SUM` condition aggregate window function.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT Id,
       SUM(id - n_Id > 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) stint
FROM (
    SELECT *,LAG(id,1,id) OVER(ORDER BY id) n_Id 
    FROM T
) t1
```

| Id | stint |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTHxQjLFa8fmLaKdpwPwDt/2)